# Reading from a text file properly

Tags: c++, string, text, vector, format

I am reading string from a line in a text file and for some reason the the code will not read the whole text file. It reads to some random point and then stops and leaves out several words from a line or a few lines. Here is my code.

```
string total;
 while(file >> word){
    if(total.size() <= 40){
        total +=  ' ' + word;
    }
    else{
        my_vector.push_back(total);
        total.clear();
    }
```

Here is an example of a file

> The programme certifies that all nutritional supplements and/or ingredients that bear the Informed-Sport logo have been tested for banned substances by the world class sports anti-doping lab, LGC. Athletes choosing to use supplements can use the search function above to find products that have been through this rigorous certification process.

It reads until "through" and leaves out the last four words.

I expected the output to be the whole file. not just part of it.
This is how I printed the vector.

```
for(int x = 0; x< my_vector.size(); ++x){
    cout << my_vector[x];
    }
```

Comment: Give us an example of the file and the output please.

Comment: Here is an example of a file "The programme certifies that all nutritional supplements
and/or ingredients that bear the Informed-Sport logo have
been tested for banned substances by the world class sports
anti-doping lab, LGC. Athletes choosing to use supplements
can use the search function above to find products that have
been through this rigorous certification process." It reads until "through" and leaves out the last four words.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to print out the data? (edit it into the question like I did please).

Comment: Also, what did you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed two things here:

First: in case when `total.size() is not <= 40 i.e >40` it moves to else part where you just update your `my_vector` but ignore the current data in `word` which you read from the file.  You actually need to to update the `total` after `total.clear()`.

Second: when your loop is terminated you ignore the data in `word` as well. you need to consider that and `push_back()`in vector (if req, depends on your program logic).

So overall you code is gonna look like this.

```
string total;
while(file >> word)
{
    if(total.size() <= 40)
    {
        total +=  ' ' + word;
    }
    else
    {
        my_vector.push_back(total);
        total.clear();
        total +=  ' ' + word;
    }
}
my_vector.push_back(total);//this step depends on your logic 
                           //that what u actually want to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop finishes when the end of file is read. However at this point you still have data in `total`. Add something like this after the loop:

```
if(!total.empty()) {
    my_vector.push_back(total);
}
```

to add the last bit to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. When `40 < total.size()` only `total` is pushed to `my_vector` but the current `word` is not. You should probably unconditionally append the word to `total` and then `my_vector.push_back(total)` if `40 < total.size()`.
2. When the loop terminated you still need to `push_back()` the content of `total` as it may not have reached a size of more than `40`. That is, if `total` is no-empty after the loop terminated, you still need to append it to `my_vector`.